# Protected flash video (requires HAL) on Gentoo

Tags: flash, gentoo, drm, hal

I am unable to play "protected" flash video, such as Amazon Prime Instant Video. From what I've read and uncovered, this seems to be due to a lack of HAL being installed on my computer. Confirmation that it is required for protected video can be seen towards the beginning of http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html

However, hal is not in the gentoo portage tree, and in any case has been deprecated and replaced by udev. How can I go about getting Amazon Prime Instant Video to work again? I was considering grabbing the source from http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal but the links there won't load, and trying to install it from old ebuilds or from overlays which claim to still support it (e.g. kde-sunset) result in a compilation error:

```
In file included from addon-generic-backlight.c:38:0:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmain.h:21:2: error: #error "Only <glib.h> can be included directly."
```

Has anyone else solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emerge hal-flash

That's all you gotta do these days as it is in portage.  WFM

Comment: @Chenmunka this actually solves the issue perfectly. Since it's addition into portage (the Gentoo package manager), simply installing it via the emerge command indicated solves the problem without having to manually download, patch, compile, install and configure HAL code -- I'm changing the accepted answer to this one as it more correctly reflects the current state of affairs.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in my shoes who needs to get this installed, grawity's comments to his answer hold the key on how to do it. For an explicit step-by-step:

**Step 1: Grab the code**

```
# git clone http://cgit.freedesktop.org/hal-info/
# git clone http://cgit.freedesktop.org/hal/
```

**Step 2: Install hal-info**

```
# cd hal-info
# ./autogen.sh
# make && make install
# cd ..
```

**Step 3: Fix the hal code**

To do this, replace all instances of `#include <glib/gmain.h>` with `#include <glib.h>`. You can do that with a command like:

```
# find hal -name "*.c" -print|xargs sed -i 's/#include <glib\/gmain\.h>/#include <glib\.h>/g'
```

For some reason, that missed one reference (I'm not really a regexp / sed guru) so I just did a `grep -r "#include <glib/gmain.h>" *` and fixed it manually.

**Step 4: Install hal**

```
# cd hal
# ./autogen.sh --disable-policy-kit
# make && make install
```

**Step 5: Don't forget the dbus config!**

```
# cp hal.conf /etc/dbus-1/system.d/
```

That's it! Now just run it with `hald` (/usr/local/sbin/hald)

Answer (score 1):

HAL works *on top* of udev; it has never been "replaced by" it completely; those features that were can be disabled in hal (such as ACL management). There shouldn't be any conflicts as long as Flash Player is the only user of HAL.

Comment: awesome, i'll try compiling and installing and see how it goes. I thought it had been replaced from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_%28software%29#Deprecated

Comment: gosh getting HAL to compile / install is harder than one would think

Comment: @Mala: Try using similar build options to the Arch Linux [package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=51454) -- in particular, disable the features that were moved to udev. The udev.patch may help as well.

Comment: Thanks for checking back :) I'm having the darndest time -- no ebuilds will compile, and all the release / git links on HAL's official page seem to be broken. I'll check out the AUR page and see if I can glean anything from there

Comment: I replaced the Gentoo patches with the ones in the AUR tarball (since they don't seem to be compatible with each other) but the compilation still fails with the same error as when grabbing it from an overlay (see update to my question)

Comment: (The Git trees are at http://cgit.freedesktop.org/hal/ and http://cgit.freedesktop.org/hal-info/ by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for the git links. It fails to compile with the same error when pulled from Git... I'm starting to think that it's not happy with gcc 4.6.2

Comment: No, it's not happy with changes to GLib... try replacing all `#include <glib/gmain.h>` with `#include <glib.h>`

Comment: you sir are a gentleman and a scholar.